# Swift Add custom cell on button tap

Tags: swift, swift2, tableview, uitableview

I have a table view with one custom cell that I have already built and hooked up. When the user taps the add cell button I want it to add a different custom cell. I don't know where to start this process. Do I build it on the storyboard then hide it? Or what is the best means?

Comment: I think you may want to look at this: http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create all of your custom cells in the storyboard, and then implement `UITableViewDataSource` methods, where you return whatever cells you want.

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/)